# Differential operators question

Tags: differential-operators, integrable-systems

I am getting confused on differential operators, can some please help explain the following.
Suppose I have two differential operators $B = D_x^2 + \alpha A I$ where $I$ is the identity operator and $C = uI $ where $u(x,t)$.
I would like to compute $L = BC$ for which the answer is
$L = u_{xx}I+2u_xD_x+uD_x^2+αAuI$ but I am not sure how B operates on C?

Here is my attempt:

$(D_x^2 + \alpha A I)(uI) = D_x^2uI + \alpha A I uI $

which then I simplify to:

$u_{xx}I + \alpha A u I$

which is clearly wrong

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: Why do you have $A$ on both the left and right hand sides of the equation defining $A$?

Comment: @CutOnBumInBand sorry - have edited the question

Comment: You have the answer, so my question to you would be which part are you unsure about - If you'd had $B = \alpha A I$, would you have been able to compute $BC$? And similarly for $B = D_x^2$?

Comment: @CutOnBumInBand I am unsure on the steps to reach the answer - when I attempt it, I get a different expression

Comment: If you've made an attempt, put it in your question so we can see what you've done, and then maybe see where you went wrong and point you in the right direction

Comment: @CutOnBumInBand just added my attempt - thanks

Comment: If $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \exp(x)$, then what is $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(fg)$?

Comment: @CutOnBumInBand So the mistake I am making is not using the product rule